# Strange java behaviour with conditional operator. Is it a bug?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

Can you please run the below and explain?

```
Object o = true ? new Integer(1) : new Double(2.0);
System.out.println(o);
```

I found that surprising as someone would expect 1 to be printed and not 1.0

Comment: Java is not dynamically typed.  The type of that right-hand side expression has to be established at COMPILE time, and will always be the same.  By the rules, the type of that expression is Double.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not a surprise at all, although it might seem like one. The behaviour is specified in [JLS §15.25 - Conditional Operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

> Otherwise, if the second and third operands have types that are
>   convertible (§5.1.8) to numeric types, then there are several cases:
>
> - If one of the operands is of type `byte` or `Byte` and the other is of
>     type `short` or `Short`, then the type of the conditional expression is
>     `short`.
>
>   [...]
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand
>     types, and the **type of the conditional expression is the promoted type
>     of the second and third operands.**
>
> <sub>Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may **perform unboxing conversion** (§5.1.8).</sub>

So the `Integer` and `Double` types are unboxed to their respective primitive counterparts - `int` and `double`, as a process of binary numeric promotion. And then the type of the conditional operator is the promoted type of `int` and `double`, which is `double`. Hence the result is `1.0`. And of course the final result is then boxed back to `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article published in DZone yesterday talking about it:

[Java auto unboxing gotcha](http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-auto-unboxing-gotcha)

Funny enough, the example code looks similar...