# Confusion while getting unexpected output from java program

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Object o=true?new Integer(1):new Double(1.0);
  System.out.println(o);
 }
```

I am getting **1.0** as output, first upon above else statement is unreachable but how it auto type casted.

Comment: You copied from here right ???[strange-java-behaviour-is-it-a-bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293575/strange-java-behaviour-is-it-a-bug), If no sorry. Look there.

Comment: yes and sorry @SURESH ATTA , that answer is not able to understand.

Comment: What didn't you understand in that answer?

Comment: @SURESH ATTA that question is on hold

Comment: @RohitJain what is the need for result is boxed back to Double. As I analyse else part is unreachable so I don't have to bother about it so only if part is there and it's true so if we print any object we get hashcode and if we think about wrapper class then the value of o should be 1 why it's boxed to double.

Comment: @user2826111 A well explained answers is enough. No matter weather it is on hold or closed :)

Comment: @user2826111: check the answers given below. and by the way if you print an object, the `toString()` method is called not the `hashCode()` method.

Comment: @user2826111. Because conditional operator don't work really like if-else conditional. Both the 2nd and 3rd expression has to be converted to a common type, and that is the type of the conditional expression. Doesn't matter whether 3rd expression is reachable or not. Type is already resolved to be of `Double`. Boxing is required because you can't store `double` in `Object`. So, `double` has to be boxed to `Double`.

Comment: ok @RohitJain I got it, Both the 2nd and 3rd expression has to be converted to a common type. so common type is Int?

Comment: @user2826111 Common type is the promoted type of both the operand. That is `double`. Unboxing operation is performed before numeric promotion. Please refer to the JLS section I linked in my answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JLS states that

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both
>   operands as specified by the following rules:
>   • If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.

that is in an expression

```
true? Integer(1) : Double(1.0)
```

since one of the operand here is a Double the return type is also double

Comment: To compound matters here the latter is considered dead code. So even though the 3rd operand expression can never be executed the conversion to Double still occurs. If he had said 

`true? Integer(1) : Double(2.0)`

The output would still be 1.0 and Object would be considered a Double.

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6

The keyword is "Numeric Promotion":

> Numeric promotions are used to convert the operands of a numeric
>   operator to a common type so that an operation can be performed. The
>   two kinds of numeric promotion are unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1)
>   and binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2).

sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ already gave you a link explaining your concrete example.